# My MS Access Combo Box is only working for some records

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox

I've a combo box in a tabbed Form used to find a record based on the AccountName, theres 230 names and what's baffling me is it works up to names beginning with the letter O. I've spent hours searching online for where to even start to try fix it I am new to Access and would prefer it to work without VBA. Ive deleted the combobox and tried recreating it with the Wizard and its the same everytime.

If I add 2 columns to the combo box it does work but I cant search by typing.

Any help at all would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, looking at it again, the reason it stopped on the Names beginning with O was because of the apostrophes. I took out all the apostrophes (changed O'Brien to OBrien)and its working. Is this normal? Is there certain Characters that cannot go into a Text Field?